# How to combine use of payment processor with firebase or Auth0 login?

Tags: c#, firebase, authentication, auth0, payment-processing

I am new in the software development world. I have built a C# application that will require to keep track of user progress on a certain task and possibly integration of payment processor. I have seen Auth0 implementation requirements and I am able to implement it on my app. But the problem is- Auth0 gives user token and basic information like names on its example app, but what should I do with these data?

To keep track of user progress, I will need to implement a way to store data on a server probably in firebase. But should I use that Auth0 information to create a new users and update their progress? I don't know how to use token to create a user on firebase or at least to keep track of within the app.

Please give me a direction on how should I create and keep track of users with Auth0 given tokens or other information? Can I use Auth0 tokens to identify the user without using a server like a firebase?

Or is there a better way of combining these? Like firebase login with user creation? But how do I add a payment processor then? How the payment processor will combine the firebase user database and can process payment to the right user?

I have no idea about this and posting on different sites gave me no answer, so posting on the best possible site for this. Any information would help.

Comment: Which payment processor you are planning to use?

Comment: Stripe/Similar.@Baskar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user_id from auth0 to retrieve the relevant info from your database.

Typically, the user will log in, the token will be issued from auth0, validate the token, then use the `sub` claim (the auth0 user id) to store and access data in your user db. This id can act as the connection between your db and auth0's database.